# How do I change the lag interval in an ACF plot?

Tags: r, time-series, advanced-custom-fields, lag

I currently have a time series of daily precipitation data and plotted the ACF using the code

```
precip.dat <- read.csv("Precipitation.csv") # upload the CSV file into R
precip <- precip.dat$Precipitation # create an object for daily precipitation 
precip.ts <- ts(precip, start = c(2010,5), end = c(2022,10), frequency = 184) # create time series for precipitation
acf(precip.ts, lag.max = 7) # view the ACF plot
```

When I run this code to view the ACF plot it shows lags of 0.00, 0.005, 0.01, 0.015, 0.020, 0.025, 0.030, and 0.035. I want this plot to show lags 0, 1, 2, and 3. Does anyone know how to specify/change the lag interval that is displayed on the ACF plot? Thanks.

I tried changing the lag.max to see if I could get the lag to show whole numbers/days but that didn't work.

Comment: Can you share a sample of your data in the question using `dput()` to make your code reproducible? Where does the frequency of 184 come from? The frequency tells you how many times in a unit time interval your series was sampled. e.g. 7 if daily samples and the unit time is weeks. Try changing `frequency`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```r
acf(c(precip.ts))
```

By placing the series within `c()`, the time series attributes are removed, and the result is just a numeric vector. `acf()` gives the horizontal scale in terms of total periods. So with `frequency=184`, a lag of 1 on the scale corresponds to 184 observations. But when you remove the time series attributes, a lag of 1 corresponds to 1 observation.